# Looking for a way to override application.properties values during application runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq

I have written a small application to publish messages to IBM MQ using Spring boot.I have following properties in my applications.properties. Code is working when I input a destination queue name and the message without any issue, Now I want to input the queue manager name and based on the queue manager name ibm.mq.QueueManager,ibm.mq.connName should be changed. Appreciate if someone give me a suggestion. Do I need to come up with a separate method with a MQ connection initiation?

```
ibm.mq.QueueManager=KAU.TST
ibm.mq.channel=KAU.CONN
ibm.mq.connName=192.168.1.26(1540)
ibm.mq.user=
ibm.mq.password=
```

I have included following setter in my controller class, but it seems it does not overriding the property file as I intended.

```
    @Value("${ibm.mq.QueueManager:KAU.TST}")
    String destQM;


    public void setQueueManager(String destQM) {
        this.destQM= destQM;
    }
```

current method of publishing messages

```
    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    public String dropmessage()
    {
        
          try{
              //String msg="IBM MQ integration testing with spring boot";
              jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(qname, msg);
              System.out.println("Message Sent :"+msg);
              return "OK";
          }catch(JmsException ex){
              ex.printStackTrace();
              return "FAIL";
          }     
        
    }
```

Comment: And why adding a setter should magically change the queuemanager? How to override properties is [explained in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config). This is assuming those are part of the `application.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use factory customizer methods to make dynamic changes to qmgr configurations. For example:

```
@Bean
public MQConnectionFactoryCustomizer myCustomizer() {
  MQConnectionFactoryCustomizer c = new MQConnectionFactoryCustomizer() {
  @Override
  public void customize(MQConnectionFactory factory) {
    System.out.println("Changing port for " + factory.getQueueManager());
     try {
       factory.setPort(1415);
     } catch (JMSException e) { 
     }
   }
 };
 return c;
}
```